# Set background colour of description in tiles

Tags: web-part, css, html, script, tiles

my tiles look like this:

[image]

I know how to change the darker background (from heading) but how can I change the background of the description (shows up when going with mouse over tile) and the surrounding of the heading?

Thanks!!

update:
with the code 
 .ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium { background-color: red; }

my tile looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Just the background of the actual description or the whole hover background?

Comment: Use the F12 panel and check the CSS for the :hover state . You can select the element and force the hover state with the inspector. See: http://i.imgur.com/TUZM3gX.jpg

Comment: the grey colour behind 'Organisation'. There is a dark grey (I can make it darker/lighter) and a light grey sorounds the darker grey (I do not know how to change that colour).

Answer (score 0):

Use ".ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox" class and you can change the backgroundcolor of description box.

refer the below screen to provide description for tile view,

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Could you type in the complete code? Because I tried something similar before and it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe like this: <script><style type="text/css">.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox{background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);}
<\style>
<\script>

Comment: use this for description background color change:  
<style>
.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

Comment: Hi! I tried that code but now it looks like the picture above (with the red part on the picture) :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below css and works for me

`.ms-tileview-tile-root:hover .ms-tileview-tile-descriptionSmall, 
.ms-tileview-tile-root:hover .ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium, 
.ms-tileview-tile-root:hover .ms-tileview-tile-descriptionLarge {
   background-color: blue;
}`

[image]

To change complete tile description and title background on hover

`.ms-tileview-tile-root:hover .ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium {
    background-color: blue;
}`

Comment: Hi! So first: thanks for your answer. But how can I change the whole background that is coming up when going over the tile with the mouse. So the grey background behind the blue part. In fact I just want to change the transparency to make the description text easier to read. But I think if there is a square before the rest this doesn't look as nice..

Comment: For changing whole background on hover I have added second snippet below the image.